# using the bind() method in React Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

While surfing on the web about `React Hooks` I ran into an example that is using `.bind()` method in a `React Functional Component` without really explainig why. Please correct me if I was wrong, I learned that there's no need to `bind` functions/callbacks in `React Functional Components` since there is no `this` in functions.
**example 1 using bind method :**

```
const [obj, setObj] = useState({ a: 1, b: 1 });
  const handleClick = (val) =>
    setObj({
      ...obj,
      [val]: obj[val] + 1
    });
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick.bind(null, "a")}>add to A</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick.bind(null, "b")}>add to B</button>
    </div>
  );
```

**example 2 without bind method :**

```
const [obj, setObj] = useState({ a: 1, b: 1 });
  const handleClick = (val) =>
    setObj({
      ...obj,
      [val]: obj[val] + 1
    });
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick("a")}>add to A</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick("b")}>add to B</button>
    </div>
  );
```

I would really appreciate an explanation of the difference between **example 1** and **example 2**
or even if the **example 1** is a valid way in React functional Components.
thanks for your help :)

Comment: there's not really any difference. I prefer example 2 because it's more obvious what it's doing - and I'm pretty sure this is what you'd find in most examples.

Comment: by the way this use of `bind` is nothing to do with `this`, even though that's the most common use of the method (including inside React class components!). Note how the "this argument" is set to `null` in your example - so it's essentially ignored. This is using the second - and quite unrelated - feature of `bind`, of partially applying arguments to functions. See [this explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#partially_applied_functions) on MDN.

Comment: `bind` will also make the implicitly passed `event` argument the last parameter instead of the first. (not apparent in your example, but a notable difference)